# JSON - Normalize de format inside

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have converted an array in `JSON`. But the conversion puts arrays inside the `JSON` object.

**My conversion is this:**

```
{"title":"acastro","description":"teste acastro 4","category_id":29,"region_id":3,"city_id":3158063,"district_id":"1","contact":{"person":"Classe Car"},"0":{"make":"Mercedes-Benz"},"1":{"model":"GLC 220"},"2":{"engine_code":"Classe A"}
```

Have you can beginning in key `"0":{"make":"Mercedes-Benz"}`, the interior of the JSON changes anI i can not submit it to an api.

I need my JSON object to be entirely like its beggining:
`"title":"acastro","description":"teste acastro 4","category_id":29,"make":"Mercedes-Benz","model":"GLC220",..`.

and so on.

I tried with `json_encode` and `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` but without luck.

Any solutions?

Comment: What does the array look like?

Comment: Can provide the PHP variable that you use to convert JSON

Comment: please add php code that you use to decode json

Comment: $param1 = json_encode($param, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($param1);die();
            echo "</pre>";

Comment: The array is very big...

Comment: Basically judging by the json string your array has arrays as values... Maybe you want to work on that so you only have string values in there?

Comment: Its a nice sugestion, maybe converting to string with implode or json_decode()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code but its not tested:

```
$json   =   '{"title":"acastro","description":"teste acastro 4","category_id":29,"region_id":3,"city_id":3158063,"district_id":"1","contact":{"person":"Classe Car"},"0":{"make":"Mercedes-Benz"},"1":{"model":"GLC 220"},"2":{"engine_code":"Classe A"}}';

    $newArr     =   array();
function recursiveArrayShiftToRoot($array, &$newArr=array()){
    global $newArr ;
    foreach($array as $index=>$eachMixVal){
        if(is_array($eachMixVal)){
            recursiveArrayShiftToRoot($eachMixVal);
        }else{
            $newArr[$index] =   $eachMixVal;
        }
    }
}
recursiveArrayShiftToRoot(json_decode($json, true), $newArr);
```

[image]

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function recursiveArrayShiftToRoot(), 1 passed

Comment: recursiveArrayShiftToRoot($eachMixVal);
It lacks 2nd argument.

Comment: Let me test it, give me 5 min.

Comment: You can see the above attached screenshot. Its working with multidimentional array as well.

Comment: For 2nd argument i set the default value as array.